# php_beautifier 0.1.15 not working with php8.0.30

Tags: php, php-beautifier

I have installed php_beautifier on Centos Stream 9, with the following resulting environment:

```
[root@localhost kyle\]# uname -a
```

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.14.0-391.el9.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Nov 28 20:35:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
\[root@localhost kyle\]# php --version
```

```
PHP 8.0.30 (cli) (built: Aug  3 2023 17:13:08) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
```

```
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
```

```
Zend Engine v4.0.30, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

```
with Zend OPcache v8.0.30, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Running without any args gets an error:

```
# php_beautifier
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, resource given in /usr/bin/php_beautifier:186
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/bin/php_beautifier(186): implode()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/bin/php_beautifier on line 186
```

As does attempting to beautify a file:

```
[root@localhost]# php_beautifier --input rob.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, bool given in /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier.php:1242
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Filter/Default.filter.php(151): PHP_Beautifier->decIndent()
#1 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Filter.php(196): PHP_Beautifier_Filter_Default->t_close_brace()
#2 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier.php(749): PHP_Beautifier_Filter->handleToken()
#3 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Batch.php(301): PHP_Beautifier->process()
#4 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Batch/Output.php(50): PHP_Beautifier_Batch->callBeautifier()
#5 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Batch/Output/Files.php(43): PHP_Beautifier_Batch_Output->beautifierProcess()
#6 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Batch/Output/Files.php(78): PHP_Beautifier_Batch_Output_Files->get()
#7 /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier/Batch.php(274): PHP_Beautifier_Batch_Output_Files->save()
#8 /usr/bin/php_beautifier(211): PHP_Beautifier_Batch->save()
#9 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/pear/PHP/Beautifier.php on line 1242
[root@localhost]#
```

Debugging a package that should work seems like a losing strategy.    I am wondering if there is a version incompatability issue or some other problem.

I was expecting pho_beautifier to work.   Although "php_beautifier --help" worked, the actual functionality appears broke.

Comment: Hm, php_beautifier 0.1.15 was released ~14 years ago for PHP5 (unless I'm reading about the wrong package) - why do you think it would still work nowadays on PHP8?

Comment: `Debugging a package that should work seems like a losing strategy` ... "should work" is a relative phrase. Very old code vs. newer and more up-to-date software are typically always a losing strategy. Maybe try to figure out how/why the `$array` is true or false could be a start, and the old package _might_ work, but there could very likely be other error(s) after resolving that one.